# JQuery Control in MVC Application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

This is possibly a very simple question, but I have tried looking it up but must be missing something obvious and `jquery` is very new to me.

I'm trying to get a `jquery` `DateTimePicker` to work but I keep getting the following exception:

`0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object`

This happens on the code I've got here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#StartDateTime').datepicker();
        $('#EndDateTime').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Both Start and EndDateTime are input controls I've put on my View.

In my Scripts I've got lots of jquery references which I thought would have worked, such as:
jquery-ui-1.8.24.js
jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
jquery-ui.min.js

I have tried adding the time picker as an added option for the `BundleConfig` in the Global.asax.cs page but that didn't work either.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*","~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon*")); // Added by me

}
```

Obviously I'm missing something, but I can't think what.  Can anybody spot anything amazingly obvious?

Comment: Yea i'm pretty sure you just need like the main jquery script. Should look something like jquery-2.0.3.js

Comment: seems you have many jquery-ui, but not... jquery itself. By the way, I don't think you should have the "non-min" and the "min" version together.

Comment: I agree the error is because the main jQuery script file isn't being loaded for whatever reason.

Comment: can show the pattern of putting the js files

Comment: I've updated the original post with all the BundleConfig code (excluding the CSS additions) as this already contained the calls to add, what I assume to be, the main jquery file.

Answer (score 1):

In your list of references, you are missing the main [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) reference. The fact that it does not recognize the `$` would indicate this is your problem. Add this and reference it above your other jquery scripts (If you do already have it, make sure it's first as all other jquery libraries will depend on it).

Comment: I've updated the main post with the full piece of code that I assume you mean, I may have caused some confusion by only posting what I added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference to the core jquery library **BEFORE** you add your reference to `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon`. **Something like this**:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"));
```

The reason being is that your add-on has a **dependency** on the jquery core library and therefor needs to be loaded **AFTER** the jquery core library is referenced.

Comment: You can also use the followings:
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Sorry yeah I have that added, I only included the timepicker option on the off chance I got something wrong. I shall update the code with the full RegisterBundles method excluding CSS.